# how to save the texbox value that is place in dojo data grid

Tags: datagrid, dojo

I have a dojo data grid with a text box and other read only values that come from store. On submit I want to send the texbox values along with the other ready only values to the java controller for further processing. I am not able to find out a right way to handle this case. Can someone help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid itself is not designed to communicate with your backend directly. Although you could overrride it, it isn't *The Dojo Way!*

What you need to do is to attach your dgrid to a store like `dojo/store/JsonRest` or your own store based on transport mechanism (AJAX, Polling, Socket etc.) through `grid.set('store', store)`

Your grid will call `grid.save()` and that will initiate a `grid.store.put` which will inturn send an AJAX request to your back end. Refer to `dojo\store\JsonRest` and let me know if you need more help.